# How can I make a specific part of my model follow certain curve without affecting the rest of it?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I have this model and I want the part on the back to be curved, it doesn't have to exactly follow the selected curve that's just the general idea. If I use a curve modifier all the model gets affected and the lattice modifier don't seem to be good to deform with curves. I also would prefer to don't use those modifiers because they turn my model upside down and I can't model it with precision if that happens (moving the axis, rotation and origins don't solve this).

[image: Lateral view]

[image: Another view]

Comment: Try playing around with _proportional editing_ (Shortcut key - O). You can also turn it on from the little icon that looks like a target in the top center of your viewport. There is also a dropdown menu next to it with more edit options. When you go to move a vertex (with proportional edit enabled), scroll your mousewheel to change the size of the "circle of influence". Try with different edit options (ex, smooth, sharp, inverse square, etc...) You will need more horizontal loop cuts on the extruded part of the helmet as well, because those long rectangles will never bend the way you want.

Comment: That's what I needed, thank you.